# Looking for a free C# library that allows me to get/read PDF bookmarks/outlines/links position/dimension

Tags: pdf, c#, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor

As the title says, given a PDF file, I want to be able to access all of its bookmarks, reading their corresponding title and dimensions / position in the PDF.

I am looking for a C# library (free for commercial use) that allows this.

Closest I managed was PDFiumViewer, using the GetPageLinks method, however, it did not show all links, only some of them. I also tried PDFSharp, did not manage to make sense of it.

I would love help with any of this, whether recommendation for a library that does this, or help seeing what I'm missing in the libraries that I've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Syncfusion High-performance .NET PDF Framework

- Create, read, and edit PDF files with just a few lines of code.
- Convert 20+ of the most common and popular document formats to PDF.
- View and review PDF files seamlessly in your apps.

https://www.syncfusion.com/document-processing/pdf-framework/net

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, but it is not free for commercial use.

Comment: Companies and individuals with less than $1 million USD in annual gross revenue and 5 or fewer developers can use it .
Note: An entity or organization may not have ever received more than $3,000,000 USD in capital from an outside source, such as private equity or venture capital, in order to be eligible for the Community License.